# Compare a value to a potentially large data set

Tags: mysql, algorithm, data-structures, geolocation

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to compare a value against a potentially enormous dataset. The problem is I don't know exactly what I am looking for. I have done some research on sorting and searching algorithms (non-cs major here) but most of what I have found returns differences or sorts the data. While this may come in handy I am trying to figure out a way to (or if I am thinking of this correctly) to minimize the results to be calculated.

The application will compare a given users latitude and longitude when making a post (lat/long tied to post not user) to every other post in the database to return all posts  within a given distance (lets say 5 miles).

The first version of my application (still in development) simply compares the post to every other post in the database to return the exact distance between posts and displays only those within a 5 mile radius. It works fine with test users numbering in the dozens, but I realize that when it goes live there could one day be millions of users/posts and performing these calculations in PHP on the entire database would not be ideal.

An idea I had is to create a temporary table with posts from just the last 72 hours that have a latitude of +/- 5 minutes (~5 miles) of the querying post and then use PHP to calculate the actual distance of this smaller set effectively eliminating non-relevant longitudes. I could explore using longitude in this query as well but since it has a varying distance it would not be incredibly accurate. Possibly using an overstated 5 degrees in longitude will still fall within 5 miles at the poles and still reduce the size of the dataset at the equator (I don't anticipate having many users at the poles btw).

Is this sound or is there a better way?

Any ideas or suggested readings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is certainly the way to go if possible, the issue though is that you are looking for "all posts within a given radius", of which there may be a lot (100s to even 10000s). However, you may want to also consider clustering posts to avoid cases of high concentration, along with some other benefits, at the cost of the radius (5 km) being approximate. A way this can be done is to make use of linear algorithm for [smallest-circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_circle_problem).

```
def cluster_posts(points,cluster_radius):
    clusters = dict()
    for p in posts:
        # This inner part is also done whenever a new post is added
        clusters[p] = Cluster([p])
    points_set = set(points)
    While points_set:
        # This inner part is also done whenever a new post is added
        p = points_set.pop()
        q = kd_tree.nearest_neighbor(p)
        dist = distance(p,q)
        radius_p = clusters[p].smallest_circle_radius()
        radius_q = clusters[q].smallest_circle_radius()
        if radius_p + dist + radius_q < cluster_radius:
            new_cluster = clusters[p].merge(clusters[q])
            r = new_cluster.smallest_circle_radius()
            if r < cluster_radius:
                c = new_cluster.smallest_circle_center()
                points_set.remove(q)
                clusters.remove(q)
                clusters.remove(p)
                kd_tree.remove(p)
                kd_tree.remove(q)
                points_set.add(c)
                kd_tree.add(c)
                clusters[c] = new_cluster
```

The above tries to combine two clusters into a single cluster based on the cluster_radius. There is some room for optimization, but it should run in around O(N log N). Since I didn't code certain classes and functions, it won't compile, but hopefully it gets the idea across. It assumes that the points (lat/long of the posts) are already entered into a k-d tree. It's also probably not a bad idea to convert the lat and long from degrees-minutes-seconds.fractions to seconds.fractions. 5 km is probably small enough to be able to treat the coordinates as Euclidean points without introducing too much error, since it's approximate anyway with the clustering.

A query simply finds all clusters within (query_radius - cluster_radius) of the user's position via the k-d tree, and at least includes the nearest cluster. The numbers you gave would make the query radius 5 km. A few possibilities for cluster radius:

- 5 km (full radius)
- 2.5 km (half radius)
- A few hundred feet (cluster by blocks)

Comment: In retrospect, the coordinates should be transformed into 3d points, and a 3D kd-tree should be used. Although, the issue will only be noticeable along the two lines where negative lat/long becomes positive lat/long.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably want to store your posts in a database (the table would contain latitude, longitude, and the post text, and you'd index latitude and longitude), and then perform a range query to retrieve the appropriate posts (select * from posts where (latitude between 10 and 20) and (longitude between 40 and 50))

If all of the data is in memory then a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) or [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is the data structure you want, but if you're talking about having millions of posts then you'll want to use a database

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a good free lightweight database you can use